# Change the template used by the function LaTeX-section (C-c C-s)

Tags: latex, auctex

In a document using LaTeX-mode (i.e., AUCTeX), the command `LaTeX-section` (`C-c C-s)` inserts a small template corresponding to a LaTeX sectioning element. How can these inserted templates be modified?

The original function inserts something like this:

```
\section{A Section}
\label{a-label}
```

And let's say that, instead, I'd like the command to insert something different, like:

```
\section{\color{red}A Section}\label{a-label}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the idea behind LaTeX.  If you want your titles to be red, use a package like `titlesec` and change the color on a global level.  Adding the color command inside the `\section` macro is a bad idea.

Comment: You seem to have misinterpreted my question. The questions is not about changing the color of the section heading, it's about controlling what the command `LaTeX-section` inserts into the buffer. Changing the color was just an arbitrary example.

Comment: @UndeadKernel - I simply read your question and tried to interprete as little as possible.  Maybe you edit your question and show a real life showcase as a MWE.